# paypal expresscheckout in oscommerce get this error The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts

Tags: oscommerce

I am working with the PayPal express checkout  and am having issues in discount code. Below are my parameters:

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=CAD
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=test
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=125.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=125.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=12.50
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=112.50
```

Its returning the following error

```
Array ( [TIMESTAMP] => 2013-09-02T08:45:26Z [CORRELATIONID] => b5acd1c6276c4 
[ACK] => Failure 
[VERSION] => 85.0 
[BUILD] => 7539191 
[L_ERRORCODE0] => 10413 
[L_SHORTMESSAGE0] => Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional     error messages for details. 
[L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.    [L_SEVERITYCODE0] => Error )
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=CAD
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=test
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=125.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=125.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPDISCAMT=0.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_HANDLINGAMT=12.50
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=137.50
```